# Particular wifi is not visible in wifi settings

Tags: networking

A particular Wi-Fi is not listed in Wi-Fi settings (earlier, I was able to connect to it).

Other Wi-Fi connections are visible and no issue found in connecting with them.
The one I expect to see in the list is visible on all other devices and no issue is encountered on them.

Previously, I was not facing this issue on my Ubuntu laptop.

Known Wi-Fi networks have the information.

Adding entry in `hidden network` list also won't help.

Note: I was able to connect to this network once, after the issue started. But after that I am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I know it might seem trivial, but have you checked that the frequency band of this particular network matches one of the frequencies that your wireless adapter support?

I used to have a similar problem in which sometimes the router would change the frequency to 5GHz and I couldn't see the network anymore because my wireless adapter could only connect to networks in the 2,4GHz band. I never found out why the frequency would randomly change, but eventually after realizing this and setting it back to 2,4GHz it stopped doing it, and I had no more connectivity problems.

Comment: Thanks Zelethil, I will check the same.